# Multi threading null pointer exception java

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, null-pointer

This **code works fine**, I mean the **multi thread** part..
the only problem is that I get a **NPE** just only if I call **save** method

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at app.Controller.handleClient(Controller.java:54)
>           at app.Controller.run(Controller.java:109)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

How can I handle this? Thank you

**coding section**

```
BlockingQueue<Client> clients_list;

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

for (Client client: clients_list) {
        Runnable worker = new Controller(client);
        executor.execute(worker);
}

public Controller(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
}
```

// Controller class implements Runnable, here run method
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do some stuff on client
        // then save data into a file
        handleClient(client);
    }

```
private void handleClient(Client client) {
    String c_rwx = client.getPermission()
    if(c_rwx.contains("allowed to:")) {
       client.setUsername = client.getUsername() + " allowed" ;
       save(client);
    }
}

private void save(Client client) {
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("done.txt");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
            fw.write("client info:" + client.getUsername() + " \n");
            // ...
            fw.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("err saving file");
        }
}
```

**FIXED EVERYTHING
added after the for**

```
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: The problem is in the " do some stuff on client" bit that you've omitted. Or it's in another `run` method that you've also omitted.

Comment: @AndyTurner if I comment save, everything goes OK..

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException at app.Controller.handleClient(Controller.java:54) -> there is no such method in the code you've posted

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed it ;)